# Populate NSMutableSet with an Object is not working - NSLog and Debugger shows Null

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4.2, nsset, nsmutableset

I am trying to create a set of objects using NSMutableSet. The object is a tag, each tag has an id and a name.

The tag class is defined like so:

```
#import "Tag.h"

@implementation Tag

@synthesize id, name;

+(id) populateTagObjectWithId:(NSString *)id andName:(NSString *)name
{
    Tag *myTag = [[self alloc] init];
    myTag.id = id;
    myTag.name = name;

    return myTag;
}
... remainder of code snipped out
```

Somewhere else in my application I use SQLite to fetch tags in the TAG table. I iterate using a while loop, for each iteration I build a tag object and then try to add it to the set. Code below:

```
... previous code snipped out...
NSMutableSet *thisTagSet;

while(sqlite3_step(tag_statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
{
    NSString *thisTagId     = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(tag_statement, 0)];
    NSString *thisTagName   = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(tag_statement, 1)];

    [thisTagSet addObject:[Tag populateTagObjectWithId:thisTagId andName:thisTagName]];

    ... rest of code snipped out...
```

So, as I mentioned, as I iterate through this while loop, i get the object and its id and name ARE populating (I have confirmed this by inspecting the debugger and also using NSLog). The thisTagSet NSMutableSet however remains empty even though I'm using the addObject method. Is there something I'm doing wrong here? I have also tried separating out the two steps like so:

```
Tag *thisTagObject = [Tag populateTagObjectWithId:thisTagId andName:thisTagName];
[thisTagSet addObject:thisTagObject];
```

Again, the same result. I successfully get a thisTagObject, but nothing in the thisTagSet...

Comment: Did you initialize your set using `-[NSMutableSet new]` or an other initialization method?

Comment: NSMutableSet *thisTagSet = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init] --- did the trick, ugh! How did I overlook this? Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading your code two things pop out:

You're not initializing your NSMutableSet, and you're leaking your tags by returning a retained object in your class method.

Edit: Added leak-fix code

```
+(id)tagObjectWithId:(NSString *)id andName:(NSString *)name
{
    Tag *myTag = [[self alloc] init];
    myTag.id = id;
    myTag.name = name;

    return [myTag autorelease];
}
```

2nd edit: The code above only applies as long as ARC is disabled. Otherwise it is not needed as ARC takes care of the memory management.

Comment: Thanks for answering, Yes, I have fixed the init problem. How do I fix the memory leak?

Comment: Using autorelease in your `+populateTagObjectWithId:andName:` method. Like this: `return [anInst autorelease]`

Comment: Thanks again for the feedback however I'm using ARC. ARC prohibits the use of autorelease as its no longer needed (as I understand it).

Comment: Under ARC there's no need to release as you said and the leak won't happen.